# IE and Nuget won't work. Chrome does

Tags: visual-studio, proxy, nuget

First, a bit about environment. I'm using a Macbook with Windows 8 as a virtual machine. I'm also behind a proxy for work. When building my solution, I get the error message: "uget package restore failed for project . Unable to connect to remote server". I have connection because Chrome works just fine. But I just read that nuget uses IE's proxy configuration, so I opend IE and it's not working either. It just gives me a "This page can't be displayed" message. However, checking the proxy setting in IE, they seem to be correct. An y suggestions?

Comment: The IE settings `seem to be correct`?  What are the settings?  http://smallbusiness.chron.com/check-proxy-settings-ie-44806.html

Comment: And can you get to any websites using IE?